# Will a "standard" "Made for iPhone" headset's remote control button work with a Samsung Galaxy Mini S5570?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, 4.2-jelly-bean, remote-control, headset, samsung-galaxy-mini

Running either latest stock Gingerbread or custom CyanogenMod Jelly Bean?

By *will the button work* I mean either by the operating system or by a 3rd party app from our nice selection: [See Izzy's answer on How can I control both volume and track skip on my Android device from my headphones?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30674/how-can-i-control-both-volume-and-track-skip-on-my-android-device-from-my-headph/30677#30677)

I need proper music support on this device, skip track, fast forward and rewind (for podcasts).

Answer (score 2):

It should work IMO. I have used a standard Galaxy Nexus earphone on my iPod Touch; it could do everything from skipping to record voice etc.